# Is it possible to find $(x_{r_n})$ of $(x_n)=(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k})_n$ such that, $\lim_n|x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}|\ne0?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence $(1,1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3},....)$ i.e. $(x_n)_n=(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k})_n$

Is it possible to find a subsequence $(x_{r_n})$ of $(x_n)$ such that, $$\lim_n|x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}|\ne0?$$

Comment: If $x_n$ is what I think it is, then $x_n\to0$, and therefore the answer is "No".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$ E.g. $x_{2^{n+1}}=x_{2^n}+\sum_{j=1+2^n}^{2^{n+1}}(1/j)$ $\ge$ $ x_{2^n}$ $+\sum_ {j=1+2^n}^{2^{n+1}}(1/2^{n+1})=$ $=x_{2^n}+1/2.$

Choose $L>0.$ Let $r_1=1.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $r_{n+1}$ be the $least$ $m>r_n$ such that $x_m>L+x_{r_n}.$

Now $r_{n+1}\ge 1+ r_n$ so $r_{n+1}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

We have from the def'n of $r_{n+1}$ that $$x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}>L\ge$$ $$\ge x_{-1+r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}=$$ $$=-\frac {1}{r_{n+1}}+x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n}.$$

Therefore $\frac {1}{r_{n+1}}\ge (x_{r_{n+1}}-x_{r_n})-L>0.$